# Mysterious crash in cppwinrt example

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, c++-winrt

I am using Visual Studio 17 v15.0 and Win 10 Anniversary Update SDK.

I build the following code (basically [sample in github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/10.0.14393.0/Samples/Ocr)) with `cl /EHsc /O2 /DUNICODE /bigobj /await /std:c++latest`, with `/MT` or `MD`. It compiles without error.

If I run when `"message.png" **is not** present in current directory, exception will be thrown, caught and reported with printf, then exit without crashing.

If I run when `"message.png" **is** present in current directory, "Hello World!" will be printed, then crash for no reason.

Weird thing is If I run it inside GDB debugger, GDB always say the program exits normally (and indeed no crash happen).

GDB output:

```
[New Thread 1364.0x2324]
[New Thread 1364.0x624]
[New Thread 1364.0x12cc]
[New Thread 1364.0x58c]
[New Thread 1364.0x1134]
[New Thread 1364.0x10d8]
[New Thread 1364.0x18a8]
[New Thread 1364.0x1794]
[New Thread 1364.0x20e8]
[New Thread 1364.0x2204]
[New Thread 1364.0x1030]
[New Thread 1364.0x1474]
Hello world!
[Thread 1364.0x10d8 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x624 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x20e8 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x1794 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x18a8 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x58c exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x1134 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x12cc exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x8d0 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x2324 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x1b38 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x2204 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x1030 exited with code 0]
[Thread 1364.0x1474 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 1364) exited normally]
```

Code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp") 
#pragma comment(lib, "pathcch")

#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Media.Ocr.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Networking.Sockets.h>

#include <pathcch.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace std::chrono;

using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Imaging;
using namespace Windows::Media::Ocr;

hstring MessagePath()
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024]{};
    GetCurrentDirectory(_countof(buffer), buffer);
    check_hresult(PathCchAppendEx(buffer, _countof(buffer), L"message.png", PATHCCH_ALLOW_LONG_PATHS));
    return buffer;
}

IAsyncOperation<hstring> AsyncSample()
{
    StorageFile file = co_await StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(MessagePath());
    IRandomAccessStream stream = co_await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read);

    BitmapDecoder decoder = co_await BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(stream);
    SoftwareBitmap bitmap = co_await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

    OcrEngine engine = OcrEngine::TryCreateFromUserProfileLanguages();
    OcrResult result = co_await engine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);
    return result.Text();
}

int main()
{
    init_apartment();

    try
    {
        printf("%ls\n", AsyncSample().get().c_str());
    }
    catch (hresult_error const & e)
    {
        printf("hresult_error: (0x%8X) %ls\n", e.code(), e.message().c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the code does not crash with GDB attached, did you try putting print statements in your code, to find the spot where the crash occurs?

Comment: I build with /MT and /MTd and debug with vscode, set breakpoint at printf as suggested, keep step into, but end up at symbol that is secret VC++ internal source code. Always exit normally like GDB. Any idea?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think I found the root cause, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `hstring` returned by `AsyncSample().get()` is not null terminated, so `printf` crashes.

```
try
{
    auto ans = AsyncSample().get();
    printf("[%u]: ", ans.size());
    auto s = ans.c_str();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
        printf("%lc", s[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is accurate. `HSTRING`s are always zero-terminated. And with `winrt::hstring` being just a wrapper around `HSTRING`, there's little reason to believe, that it would violate those rules. How did you verify, that the returned value weren't zero-terminated?